# get date oldest file in directory exclude files php

Tags: php, arrays, date

I want to get the date of the oldest file in a directory.
I know how to get the oldest but I want it to exclude files like .png .jpg etc.
I tried this code but it won't work:

```
<?php 

$files = glob( 'test/*.*' );
$exclude_files = array('*.jpg', '*.bit', '*.png', '*.jpeg');
if (!in_array($files, $exclude_files)) {
array_multisort(
array_map( 'filemtime', $files ),
SORT_NUMERIC,
SORT_ASC,
$files
);
}

echo  date ("d F Y .", filemtime($files[0]));

?>
```

Now it gets the date of the oldest file but i want it without the .jpg etx. files

How do i do this?

Comment: You are using `in_array` incorrectly. You should try `array_filter` and build a callback function to remove the unwanted files. First output the resulting array (`$files`) to see how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) will return an array of files to you, you should be able to use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter-out any of the files that contain extensions you don't like:

```
$files = array_filter(glob('test/*.*'), function($file) {
    // get the file's extension
    $ext = substr($file, strrpos($file, '.'));

    // check if the extension is in the list we don't want:
    return !in_array($ext, array('.jpg', '.bit', '.png', '.jpeg'));
});
```

Comment: Or `array_filter(array_map(...))`, and return null in your callback if the extension check fails

Comment: @onetrickpony Correct; combining them would be a good way to go in the long-run. I focused on the "ignoring files with certain extensions" primarily because that's the area the OP's having difficulties overcoming; that, and they may want to do more with the list of files too (doubtful, but possible =P).